# Aborting code execution in a Python Process without terminating the process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, flask-socketio

Let's say I have a (websocket) API, `api.py`, as such:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from worker import Worker

app = Flask()
socketio = SocketIO(app)
worker = Worker()
worker.start()

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print("Client", request.sid, "connected")

@socketio.on('get_results')
def get_results(query):
    """
    The only endpoing of the API.
    """
    print("Client", request.sid, "requested results for query", query)
    # Set the worker to work, wait for results to be ready, and
    # send the results back to the client.
    worker.task_queue.put(query)
    results = worker.result_queue.get()
    emit("results", results)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print("Client", request.sid, "disconnected, perhaps before results where ready")
    # What to do here?

socketio.run(app, host='')
```

The a API will serve many clients but only has a single worker to produce the results that should be served. `worker.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.task_queue = Queue()
        self.result_queue = Queue()
        self.some_stateful_variable = 0
        # Do other computationally expensive work
        
    def reset_state(self):
        # Computationally inexpensive.
        pass

    def do_work(self, task):
        # Computationally expensive. Takes long time.
        # Modifies internal state.
        pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.task_queue.get()
            results = self.do_work(task)
            self.result_queue.put(results)
```

The worker gets a request, i.e. a task to do, and sets forth producing a result. When the result is ready, the client will be served it.

But not all clients are patient. They may leave, i.e. disconnect from the API, before the results are ready. They don't want them, and the worker therefore ends up working on a task that does not need to finish. That makes other client in queue wait unnecessarily. How to avoid this situation, and get the worker to abort executing `do_work` for a task that does not need to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In client side: when user closes browser tab or leave the page send request to your Flask server, the request should contain id of the task you would like to cancel.
2. In server side put cancel status for the task in database or any shared variable between Flask Server and your Worker Process
3. Divide Task processing in several stages and check status of task in database before each stage, if status is canceled - stop the task processing.

Another choice for point 1 is to do some monitoring in Server side in separate Process - count interval between status requests from client side.

Comment: I was hoping it was possible to use (`signal`) and to send some sort of signal to the process

Comment: @tsorn yes you can send signal to child process if you know its id, then you have to handle the signal in main thread of your child process, so it will be instead of point number 2, point 1 and 3 will be the same. From my opinion shared variable is easier to use.

Comment: @tsorn any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I've handled similar problems by launching an entirely separate process via:

```
sp.call('start python path\\worker.py', shell=True)
```

worker.py would then report its PID back to the api.py via redis, then its straightforward to kill the process at any point from api.py

Of course, how viable that is for you will depend on how much data resides within api.py and is shared to worker.py - whether its feasible for that to also pass via redis or not is for you to decide.

The added benefit is you decouple socket from heavy compute - and you can go quasi-multi-core (single thread per worker.py). You could go full multi core by incorporating multiprocessing into each worker.py if you wished.